# How to disable close button on a window in another process with C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I need to disable the close button on a window from another process. I have its handle in `hWnd` and I try to do this:

```
DWORD dwCStyle = GetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE);
SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE, dwCStyle | CS_NOCLOSE);
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect on that window.

PS. I test this on Vista. Both processes don't run elevated.

PS2. I check the result both "visually" and by using Spy++. The `hWnd` handle seems to point to the right window.

Comment: What does `SetClassLongPtr` return?

Comment: @ahmd0, And what does `GetLastError` return? "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: @chris: Sorry, forgot to mention. GetLastError also returns 0. Do I need to enable any special privileges for my process?

Comment: If I change `hWnd` to point to the main window in my own process, then this method succeeds and the close button is grayed out.

Comment: It's possible you might have to inject the code into the other process.

Comment: @chris: Oops, just realized that I wasn't calling GetLastError immediately after that API. It actually returns 5, which is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Crap!

Comment: You can try adjusting your process's token's privileges. I'm not sure if you need the same privileges to inject the code as you do to call this.

Comment: The alternative is to patch the system menu, GetSystemMenu().  Disable the SC_CLOSE menu item.  Having this work across process boundaries is equally iffy.

Comment: @HansPassant: Wow. Amazing. I thought I would get another failure, but what would you know, the `hMenu=GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);` followed by `DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);` worked. I tried it on the Notepad and even though the X in its menu can be clicked, it doesn't do anything. (Alt+F4 works though.) Thanks. If there's no other alternative to gray it out, you may want to post it as the answer.

Comment: Don't delete it, disable it.  I'll skip, I don't want to support these kind of cross-process hacking answers.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not hacking anything. I need this to disable close button on one of our programs at the office because one lady seems to hit close on it all the time and forgets to reopen it. That's it.

Comment: @ahmd0 If she's that inept get a new lady.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Haha.

Comment: Perhaps instead of disabling the close button, just a small program to run in the background that restarts the app when/if she closes it?