# Disable Close Button In Title Bar of a WPF Window (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to know how to disable (not remove/hide) the Close button in a WPF window. I know how to hide it which makes the window's title bar look like this:

[image]

But I want to disable it meaning it should look like this:

[image]

I'm scripting in C# and using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation).

Comment: I found this link See if this [link][1] can Help:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);


    const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    const uint MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;

    const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        // Disable close button
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
        if (hMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190806103045/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2007/09/26/never-ever-close-me-how-to-disable-close-button-in-wpf/).

Make sure you set the `ResizeMode` to `NoResize`.

Comment: I used this solution but I created an extension method on Window to hold the WinApi stuff, and just called .EnsureHandle() in the method instead of needing to hook OnSourceInitialized(). Note that EnsureHandle raises OnSourceInitialize(). I didn't want to pollute this answer but I will add the code in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override and in **OnCLosing** event set e.cancel=true

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MyWindow_Closing);
}

void MyWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make button look like it's disabled.

Comment: Yes, but I want to actually disable the Close button instead of making it cancel the closing.

Comment: I am afraid you can only hide or override  in WPF please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window

Comment: @Kyle http://stackoverflow.com/a/1623991/743382 on that page seems to be *exactly* what the OP is looking for here. (Edit: I see it does a little bit more, and that little bit more is easily removed.)

Comment: @hvd The selected answer in the link removes the Close Icon from the window permanently and the output is something like the first image in this question which the user does not want .I hope i made it clear

Comment: @Kyle No, it doesn't. From the comments on that answer: "The Close button itself is disable (looks gray), but not removed."

Comment: This doesn't make button look like disabled, but this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://baxincc.cc/questions/7715/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window) which an answer using `Behavior`, `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`:

```
public class HideCloseButtonOnWindow : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<Window>
{
    #region bunch of native methods

    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(AssociatedObject).Handle;
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:w="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <w:HideCloseButtonOnWindow />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</Window>
```

Comment: This doesn't make the close button look like it's disabled, it removes it completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with win32 hackery.

I have done it this way: Get CustomChromeWindow(which will eventually look exactly like the one in picture), and just bind Command() property to viewmodel, and then set CanExecuteCommand=false, which will make the button disabled([How does one "disable" a button in WPF using the MVVM pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476686/how-does-one-disable-a-button-in-wpf-using-the-mvvm-pattern)).

There might me this way too: [How to disable close button on a window in another process with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826057/how-to-disable-close-button-on-a-window-in-another-process-with-c)

Basically, call that code with pInvoke. You can obtain WPF window handle easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a more generic version of [Yoav's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962429/disable-close-button-in-title-bar-of-a-wpf-window-c/17962671#17962671) that doesn't require adding Win API calls to your Window class, here's a extension class and method:

```
namespace WinApi
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Windows.Interop;

    public static class WinApi
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);

        const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
        const uint MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;

        const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

        public static void DisableCloseButton(this System.Windows.Window window)
        {
            // Disable close button
            IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
            IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);

            if (hMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
                EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it from your Window like so:

```
this.DisableCloseButton();

// or

WinApi.DisableCloseButton(this);
```

Since the extension uses `EnsureHandle()` you don't need to hook `OnSourceInitialized()` in your Window.

Be aware that `EnsureHandle()` raises `OnSourceInitialized()`, so don't call this until after you have done anything you want to happen prior to that call.

You can call `new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle()` in your Window code if you need to check whether the handle has already been created.