# How to disable close button WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to disable close button WPF ? i don't want to hide , i just want disable close button for the window

Is the any logic to disable close button ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962429/disable-close-button-in-title-bar-of-a-wpf-window-c

Answer (score 1):

You can code event, and it stop when you close button.
May be i speed English not good, but you see code OK.

```
    in wpf this event called Closing :
    public Window4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window4_Closing);
    }
    void Window4_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: That's not disabling the button. That's just causing it to not do anything.